# R inverse CDF for a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector which is a cumulative distribution function, let say in form

```
y=seq(0, 1.0, 0.05)
```

Now I need a function that will get inverse cdf of y, so that

```
f(0.1)=3
```

and

```
f(0.9)=19
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `which` function does this.

```
> y <- seq(0, 1.0, 0.05)
> which(y == .1)
[1] 3
> which(y == .9)
[1] 19
```

However, if you are trying to find the inverse cdf, you might have to deal with two vectors `x` and `y`, since it is possible that `x` does take only indices as values. So you might want to do this.

```
> y <- seq(0, 1.0, 0.05)
> x <- 1:21
> x[which(y == .1)]
[1] 3
> x[which(y == .9)]
[1] 19
```

Comment: `which` will not do this properly; if `Finv(x)` is your function, there is no reason to think that `x` must be *exactly equal* to a value of `y` (i.e. the probability at jump points).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thats why I wrote `x[which[]]` after that.

Comment: To be a proper inverse CDF, you should be able handle a value in [0,1] that does not appear in `y`, such as `1/3`. Plugging this into your code (`x[which(y == 1/3)]`) will return `integer(0)` (note: this is not the number 0, but rather a vector of length 0).

Comment: If there is no match in y, Finv(x) can be achieved by this code `min(x[which(y>0.995)])`.